# error "from tf2_msgs.srv ImportError: No module named srv "

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/catkin_ws/src/auto_docking/scripts/autoDocking.py", line 17, in <module>
    from tf.transformations import quaternion_from_euler
  File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tf/__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
    from tf2_ros import TransformException as Exception, ConnectivityException, LookupException, ExtrapolationException
  File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tf2_ros/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from .buffer import *
  File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tf2_ros/buffer.py", line 34, in <module>
    from tf2_msgs.srv import FrameGraph, FrameGraphResponse
ImportError: No module named srv
```

It seems that my ros has lost some tf2 library but I don't know how to reinstall it. I'm wearing a pi with raspibian and Ros Melodic

the problem appears to have arisen after I copied this package (https://github.com/ros/geometry2) to my catkin workspace and  run "catkin make"  which resulted in failure. Or the problem arose after I ran the command "sudo apt-get install ros-tf2-msgs" and then "sudo apt-get purge ros-tf2-msgs". It was the only different things I did

any suggestion?

thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/370709/error-%22from-tf2_msgs.srv-importerror:-no-module-named-srv-%22/) by [mateusguilherme](https://answers.ros.org/users/39228/mateusguilherme/) on ROS Answers with karma: 125 on 2021-01-31

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-02-01**:
Have you tried `sudo apt install --reinstall ros-melodic-tf2-msgs`?

**Comment by [mateusguilherme](https://answers.ros.org/users/39228/mateusguilherme/) on 2021-02-01**:
the command "sudo apt install --reinstall ros-melodic-tf2-msgs" resulted in "Unable to locate package ros-melodic-tf2-msgs". So I ran the command "sudo apt install --reinstall ros-tf2-msgs" but the problem persisted.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-02-01**:\

> the command "sudo apt install --reinstall ros-melodic-tf2-msgs" resulted in "Unable to locate package ros-melodic-tf2-msgs"

that package does exists, I just verified it the command in a Docker container. How did you install Melodic?

> So I ran the command "sudo apt install --reinstall ros-tf2-msgs" but the problem persisted.

That package is *not* part of ROS Melodic, and you really don't want to start mixing these with a regular ROS install.

See [wikiUpstreamPackages](https://wiki.ros.org/UpstreamPackages).

**Comment by [mateusguilherme](https://answers.ros.org/users/39228/mateusguilherme/) on 2021-02-01**:
I installed ROS some time ago and I don't remember. Everything was working and I did something wrong. I remember I had difficulty installing ROS MELODIC on the raspibian Buster. I think I followed this installation tutorial: "https://www.hackster.io/dmitrywat/ros-melodic-on-raspberry-pi-4-debian-buster-rplidar-a1m8-0d63d1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I discovered the problem, when I installed the package (https://github.com/ros/geometry2) unsuccessfully on my catkin workspace, a folder called "tf2_msgs" appeared in / home / pi / catkin_ws / devel / lib / python2 .7 / dist-packages with incomplete files. It was only necessary to remove it.

---

Originally posted by [mateusguilherme](https://answers.ros.org/users/39228/mateusguilherme/) with karma: 125 on 2021-02-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0